# Adding p-values to a violin plot in seurat

Tags: r, violin-plot, seurat

I currently have a seurat object `scData` in which I have applied module scored by using `AddModuleScore`.

`AddModuleScore(scData, features = inflam, name = "inflam_score", seed = 1, search = FALSE, assay = NULL, nbin = 21, ctrl = 100, pool = NULL)`

I've gone ahead and plotted a violin plot to see a visual by doing:
 `VlnPlot(scData, features = c("inflam_score1"), pt.size = 0) + NoLegend() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))`

Is there a way to add a p-value to the output?

I tried:

`VlnPlot(scData, features = c("inflam_score1"), pt.size = 0) + stat_compare_means()`

But get this error:

`Error in stat_compare_means() :  could not find function "stat_compare_means"`

I tried:

`VlnPlot(scData, features = c("inflam_score1"), pt.size = 0) + stat_compare_means()`

But get this error:

`Error in stat_compare_means() :  could not find function "stat_compare_means"`

UPDATE:

I needed to load the `ggpubr` package to get the p-values.

But since I have more than to 2 pair, how would I go about adding a global p-value plus the p-values for more than 2 groups.[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I tried:

```
my_comparisons <- list( c("hIgG2_mIgG2", "NIS793_mIgG2"), c("hIgG2_aIL_1b", "NIS793_aIL_1b"))
VlnPlot(fib_395, features = c("trans_score1"), pt.size = 0) + stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons) + stat_compare_means()
```

But I get this warning and no p-values show up:

```
Warning: Removed 6 rows containing missing values (geom_signif).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Updated:

Your error is very likely related to the y axis limits. The `VlnPlot()` function allocates the 'correct' amount of space for the plot, but you want to add p values above the violins and these don't 'fit' in the available space. If you increase the space available by changing `ylim()` it should work as expected:

Minimal reproducible example:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(Seurat)
#> Attaching SeuratObject
library(SeuratObject)
library(ggsignif)
library(ggpubr)

#data(package = "Seurat")
#data(package = "SeuratObject")

data(pbmc_small)

scData <- pbmc_small

cd_features <- list(c(
  'CD79B',
  'CD79A',
  'CD19',
  'CD180',
  'CD200',
  'CD3D',
  'CD2',
  'CD3E',
  'CD7',
  'CD8A',
  'CD14',
  'CD1C',
  'CD68',
  'CD9',
  'CD247'
))

AddModuleScore(object = scData, features = cd_features, name = "cd_features",
               seed = 1, search = FALSE, assay = NULL,
               nbin = 21, ctrl = 5, pool = NULL)
#> An object of class Seurat 
#> 230 features across 80 samples within 1 assay 
#> Active assay: RNA (230 features, 20 variable features)
#>  2 dimensional reductions calculated: pca, tsne

my_comparisons <- list( c("0", "1"), c("1", "2"), c("0", "2"))

VlnPlot(scData, features = "PC_1", pt.size = 0) +
  NoLegend() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  stat_compare_means()
```

[image]

Replicating the problem:

```r
VlnPlot(scData, features = "PC_1", pt.size = 0) +
  NoLegend() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons)
#> [1] FALSE
#> Warning: Removed 9 rows containing missing values (`geom_signif()`).
```

[image]

Changing `ylim()` to fix the problem:

```r
VlnPlot(scData, features = "PC_1", pt.size = 0) +
  NoLegend() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons) +
  ylim(-2, 15)
#> [1] FALSE
#> Scale for y is already present.
#> Adding another scale for y, which will replace the existing scale.
```

[image]

Same outcome using the ggsignif package (which ggpubr uses 'under the hood'):

```r
VlnPlot(scData, features = "PC_1", pt.size = 0) +
  NoLegend() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  geom_signif(comparisons = my_comparisons,
              map_signif_level = function(p) sprintf("*p = %.2g", p),
              step_increase = 0.15) +
  ylim(-2, 15)
#> Scale for y is already present.
#> Adding another scale for y, which will replace the existing scale.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi @jared_mamrot, indeed I need to load the `ggpubr` package. I updated my question to add more.

Comment: Yep - that's a known issue (e.g. https://github.com/const-ae/ggsignif/issues/48) and hopefully an easy fix - I have updated my answer @mmpp